# Is there a way to load video from azure media service at specific time via query params?

Tags: azure, azure-media-services, azure-media-player

I have a video and a list of timestamps. The timestamps are not defined as an asset filter in Azure Media Service itself.

Is there a way to load the video from Azure Media Service with a specific start time without defining asset filters? Maybe something similar with what you have in youtube when you have a link that starts at a specific second?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not specifically supported in AMS to alter the URL without using filters, but you could very simply do that client side.  Most client side libraries will let you seek.

Have you tried doing that in Javascript already? AMP may not be able to do it, but I have seen video.js and Shaka player implementations that take the t= value from the query string and just set the player.currentPosition.

Comment: sorry for late reply! the implementation is in swift, but in the end I followed the same logic!